# ASP.NET Validations: How to display validation error message and `*` at the same time when control fails validation?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-validators

I'm validating thew form and using `jQuery` dialog to show errors.

This is a `jQuery` code that displays error summary in a popup:

```
function WebForm_OnSubmit() {
    if (typeof (ValidatorOnSubmit) == "function" && ValidatorOnSubmit() == false) {
        $("#errorDisplay").dialog({
            title: "Validation Error",
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            width: 250,
            buttons: {
                Close: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This is ho I define controls:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAddName" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Name is Required" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAddEmail" Display="None" ValidationExpression="^[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+$" ErrorMessage="Invalid Email Address" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

This is `validation summary`:

Is that possible to change my validations, so, I display `*` by the failed control and still display the error message in pop up?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.
I need to change `Display=static` and put `*` between tags for both controls

Like that:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAddName" Display=Static ErrorMessage="Name is Required" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```